# Android 9. Camera crashes after taking a photo and hitting ok button(previously it was working)

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

I have been working for a year with Android Studio(I am newbie hehe) and I have never faced this problem.

When I take a photo and press the ok button the camera crashes and logs do not give me clear information, onActivityResult it is not called.
This only happens in Android 8.0(Huawei P8) and 9.0(Pixel 3XL) but not in Android 8.0(Moto e5) or Android 7.1.2(Xiaomi Redmi 4A).

**Camera intent**

```
private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA:
                placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bitmapImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                bitmapImg = scaleDown(bitmapImg, 800, true);
                imageExist = true;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImg);
                menu.findItem(R.id.rotate_photo_gallery).setVisible(true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Crash logs**

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2019-04-12 15:54:47.444 28783-28783/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 28783
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oag.b(PG:232)
        at nre.b(PG:1)
        at ekm.e(PG:5)
        at ekm.c(PG:37)
        at czm.b(PG:13)
        at czm.a(PG:33)
        at egn.onShutterButtonClick(PG:9)
        at jry.onShutterButtonClick(PG:16)
        at com.google.android.apps.camera.ui.shutterbutton.ShutterButton.performClick(PG:498)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-04-12 15:54:47.450 1165-2517/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity
2019-04-12 15:54:47.453 28783-28783/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28783 SIG: 9
2019-04-12 15:54:47.471 1165-1179/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2019-04-12 15:54:47.471 1165-1179/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2019-04-12 15:54:47.474 1165-1181/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 28990:com.google.android.GoogleCamera:crash_report/u0a112 for service com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.google.android.apps.camera.app.silentfeedback.SilentFeedbackService
2019-04-12 15:54:47.480 1165-1353/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '6ea5f67 com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2019-04-12 15:54:47.481 1165-1353/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6ea5f67 com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-04-12 15:54:47.488 28990-28990/? E/ra:crash_repor: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
```

Comment: That crash is coming from another app, not yours. Most likely, there is very little that you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that is weird because with no update to camera app it suddenly crashes always...

Comment: Did you tried to use code for getting real picture instead thumbnail only?

Comment: No, I am going to try it now.

Comment: Thank you so much @Selvin it work out!

Comment: @Sweetah, can you please tell me how were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue in Pixel.

Comment: Same here, just now demoing an app that has worked fine for months, crashed everytime I tried to take a picture on Pixel 2.   I too have the same errors @Sweetah has posted above.  Something change in the OS or what?